# How can we transfer data from one sheet to another by skipping rows in next sheet.?

Tags: excel, vba

Need to copy paste the data from one worksheet to second basis column headers matching in both worksheets and skipping one row in second worksheet where the data is getting pasted.

I am able to successfully transfer the data by matching the column headers but unable to perform the action on skipping one row on second worksheet.

```vb
Option explicit

Public ws1 As Worksheet
Public ws2 As Worksheet
Public b As Long
Public c As Long
Public i As Long

Sub pMain()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim j As Long
  Dim k As Long
  Dim m As Long
  Dim lMatch As Long

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Set ws1 = Sheets("Completed or resolved") '*** Worksheet- Completed or resolved-****
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Enter Detailed Updates Here")

  m = 1
  j = ws1.Cells.Find("*", ws1.Cells(1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row ' finding last row of worksheet-Completed or Resolved
  k = ws1.Cells.Find("*", ws1.Cells(1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column ' finding last columns of worksheet-Completed or Resolved

  For i = 1 To k

    lMatch = pMatch(ws2.Cells(1, i), ws1.Rows(1))

    If lMatch <> 0 Then
        ws1.Activate
        'ws1.Cells(i, lMatch).Copy
            ws1.Range(Cells(2, lMatch), Cells(j, lMatch)).Copy
                ws2.Activate
                Call fnRMatch
            'ws2.Cells(2, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            ws2.Cells(2, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        ElseIf lMatch = 0 Then
    End If

  Next i

  Application.CutCopyMode = False

  MsgBox "Database Saved", vbOKCancel

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

```vb
Private Function pMatch(vValue As Variant, _
                        vArray As Variant) As Long
  Dim ret As Long

  On Error Resume Next
  ret = WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(vValue), vArray, 0)
  If ret = 0 Then ret = WorksheetFunction.Match(CStr(vValue), vArray, 0)

  pMatch = ret
End Function

Function fnRMatch()
'finding last row of worksheet - Enter detailed updates here
        b = ws2.Cells.Find("*", ws2.Cells(1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
End Function

Function fnCMatch()
'finding last column of worksheet - Enter detailed updates here
        c = ws2.Cells.Find("*", ws2.Cells(1), xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

End Function
```

Currently the data is getting pasted for entire range but unable to skip blank rows in second worksheet.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of what you have and what you want?  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be userful to you in adding the information to let us better assist you.

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for the response, I resolved this.